# Selecting Nth-of-type in selenium

Tags: java, css, selenium

I'm trying to use By.cssSelector to grab the nth dom element with class c3 with a structure like this:

```
<div class="c1">
    <div class="c2">
        <div class="c3">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="c1">
    <div class="c2">
        <div class="c3">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="c1">
    <div class="c2">
        <div class="c3">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Testing my CSS selectors, I'm becoming increasingly confused.
This selector selects the 2nd instance of c2/c3 correctly:

```
.c1:nth-of-type(2)
```

while:

```
.c2:nth-of-type(2)
.c3:nth-of-type(2)
```

select nothing.

Even worse, translating this into selenium, I seem to consistently find nothing for all 3 versions. There are plenty of alternative ways to select these elements (I'll probably just do XPATH), but my lack of understanding on `nth-of-type` is driving me crazy. Can anyone offer insight to why the second 2 don't work or correct my basic lack of comprehension on this selector?

This has been in Chrome (29/30) and Firefox (24/25)

Comment: What browsers have you been testing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not enirely sure **which** one you want to select, but you should play around more with the :nth-* pseudo-classes.  Here is a CSS selector that selects all 3 c3's using `nth-child()`

```
div.c1 div.c3:nth-child(1)
```

Like i said, you haven't really specified which one you want to select.

> but my lack of understanding on nth-of-type is driving me crazy. Can anyone offer insight to why the second 2 don't work or correct my basic lack of comprehension on this selector?

One thing to keep in mind, is all of the `:nth-*()` pseudo-classes are dependent on their parents.  Let me translate your selector:

```
.c1:nth-of-type(2)
```

> Find anything with a class of c1 that is a second child.

In your case, `<body>` was most likely the parent, so...

```
<body>
  <div .c1 />
  <div .c1 /> // it highlights this one, because it's the 2nd child of the type ".c1"
  <div .c1 />
</body>
```

Now let me explain why your other selectors are not working.

Both `.c2:nth-of-type(2)` and `.c3:nth-of-type(2)` are looking at the parent's as well.  since you are specifying a parent, it's expecting `<body>` as the parent.  In your case, `<body>` isn't the parent.. the `<div .c1 />` is.  In reality, that selector is looking for the DOM -

```
<body>
  <div .c1 />
  <div .c2 /> // this **would** be the second nth-of-type, but it's not really this way. 
  <div .c1 />
</body>
```

Play around with the different css selectors and pseudo-classes at http://cssdesk.com  it's very helpful to actively experiment on your own.  you'll figure it out.

Comment: "Find anything with a class of c1 that is a second child." Thanks! That was my misunderstanding. I was interpreting it as, of all the .c1 classes, style the 2nd.

Comment: yea - the `:nth-*` pseudo-classes are a very interesting world.. especially when you mess with `n`! _(e.g. :nth-of-type(2n+3))_.  It helps just to play around with them :)

Comment: @wave this is a common mis-understanding of how the :nth- selectors work.  You are not the only one, so don't feel bad ;)