# why is nth-child(1) applying to all children?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Based on this very basic HTML structure:

```
<div>This is a cube</div>
<div>This is a triangle</div>
<div>This is a big, green circle</div>
```

I have set up the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("div:nth-child(1)").addClass("cube-text text");
    $("div:nth-child(2)").addClass("triangle-text text");
    $("div:nth-child(3)").addClass("circle-text text");

    $("div:nth-child(1)").wrap("<div class='cube shape'></div>");
    $("div:nth-child(2)").wrap("<div class='triangle shape'></div>");
    $("div:nth-child(3)").wrap("<div class='circle shape'></div>");

    $(".shape").wrap( "<div class='inner'></div>" );
    $(".inner").wrap( "<div class='outer'></div>" );
    $(".outer").wrap( "<div class='column'></div>" );

    $(".outer:nth-child(1)").addClass("cube-anim");
    $(".outer:nth-child(2)").addClass("triangle-anim");
    $(".outer:nth-child(3)").addClass("circle-anim");
});
```

For some reason, the final three lines do not seem to be working as intended. They are supposed to add the corresponding class to successive instances of the ".outer" divs that had been created in the previous lines. I have tried using various alternatives to this particular syntax, such as...

```
div .outer:nth-child

.column .outer:nth-child

.column:nth-child
```

And several others, in sort of a trial and error attempt to get the desired results.

I am trying to make each ".outer" container div possess an additional class that will be called on by CSS3 to render some @keyframe based animations.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5NEPu/

Comment: Why aren't you just adding classes and wrappers based on the text in the element ?

Comment: answered a similar question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909458/selecting-nth-of-type-in-selenium/19909750#19909750

Comment: because that is the challenge I am tasked with, adeneo

Comment: It just seems so easy -> http://jsfiddle.net/5NEPu/3/

Comment: Look at it this way... When you apply it to outer, each outer div is the first child of it's parent, therefore when you select all outer divs that are first child of their parents, you select them all. The other two do nothing because there's only one outer div per column. http://jsfiddle.net/nM2z4/

Comment: adeneo, that appears to be a valid alternative to my method. I'm just not at a level where that set up would come easily to me. I simply used a method that I imagined would work in my head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `.outer` is the only child of a `.column`, hence `:nth-child(1)` (which is functionally [equivalent to `:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)) will match all of them, while `nth-child(2)` and `(3)` will never match.

You need to use either [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```
// selects first .outer in the DOM, as :eq is 0-based
$(".outer:eq(0)").addClass("cube-anim");
```

Or [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) in an upper level with siblings:

```
// selects .outer descendant of a column that is a first child.
// NOTE:
// Only works properly if the columns are the only children of the same parent
$(".column:nth-child(1) .outer").addClass("cube-anim");
```

And I mean "only works" in that, if the first child of the columns' parent is not a column, then all columns' child index would be offset by 1. As you can see, `nth-child` is rather fragile in many use cases.

Another possible solution using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$('.triangle').closest('.outer').addClass("triangle-anim");
```

Comment: I see. It was my (incorrect) understanding that nth-child(n) would apply to the nth occurrence of that element in the document tree. I understand now that because each .outer was the first (and only) child of its parent, using my original syntax did not achieve the desired results

Comment: @BrianS I've added some extra notes about `nth-child` as well, but you've already understood it now. `=]` Thing is, nth-child will break if you wrap each element individually and you also can't prepend elements to the same container. So yeah, take extra care when using `nth-child` and avoid it when your DOM structure may change in future.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem

```
$(".outer").wrap( "<div class='column'></div>" );
```

That applies an `.column` class to everything, which makes each the `.outer` the first element of each column. Your selector should be:

```
$(".column:nth-child(1) .outer").addClass("cube-anim");
$(".column:nth-child(2) .outer").addClass("triangle-anim");
$(".column:nth-child(3) .outer").addClass("circle-anim");
```