# Get second div with selecting something in fists one

Tags: ruby, selenium

This is website code:

```
<div>
 <strong>static text</strong>
</div>
<div>
  <strong>Text that I need</strong>
</div>
```

I need to get second strong tag using first one. There is no any unique ids or classes.
These codes are finding first one,

```
@driver.find_element(:xpath, './/div/strong[contains(., "static text")]')
@driver.find_element(:xpath, './/strong[contains(., "static text")]')
```

But for using `following-sibling::*[1]` I need to find first tag,not strong.
How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as below using the axis [`following`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes) :

> The `following` axis contains all nodes in the same document as the *context* node that are after the *context* node in *document order*, **excluding** any *descendants* and **excluding** *attribute nodes* and *namespace nodes*.

```
xpath = './/div/strong[contains(., "static text")]/following::strong[1]'
@driver.find_element(:xpath, xpath)
```

[**Check here**](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Cdiv%3E%0A%20%3Cstrong%3Estatic%20text%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%3E%0A%20%20%3Cstrong%3EText%20that%20I%20need%3C%2Fstrong%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E&=&extract=%2F%2Fdiv%2Fstrong%5bcontains%28.%2C%20%22static%20text%22%29%5d%2Ffollowing%3A%3Astrong%5b1%5d&=%2F%2Fdiv%2Fstrong%5bcontains%28.%2C%20%22static%20text%22%29%5d%2Ffollowing%3A%3Astrong%5b1%5d&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath2) also.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is to use CSS's `nth-child` pseudo-selector. See "[Selecting Nth-of-type in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909458/selecting-nth-of-type-in-selenium/19909750#19909750)", where I wrote about this certain pseudo-selector using selenium.  In your case, your selector would be (assuming the parent of these 2 `<div>`s are immediate children of `<body>`:

```
@driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body div:nth-child(X) > strong')
```

replace `X` with whatever index you want.  `1` will refer to the first `<strong>` that says `"static text"` and `2` will refer to the second `<strong>` that says `"text that i need"`

Comment: The problem is that, there are a lot of divs, strongs in page, all classes and ids (not all, but most of them) are autogenerated.

Comment: that shouldn't be a problem. since my solution is index-based, it should be ok

Comment: If index was stable, I'll used xpath with number of elements, div[1] and etc. But biggest problem is that, their places are changing)))

Comment: I share in your misery.. trying to automate poorly designed apps is pretty difficult.  if you can, tell your developers to add id's and classes to elements. it will really help ;)

Comment: Yep,they already added some ids for testing) But now there is a lot new features, and design with ids will come after finishing all of them(