# How to navigate to a sibling <p> element using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to navigate to the sibling `<p>` element using Selenium that has no id/class attributes. This is my HTML:

```
<div class="content1">              
    <div class="bold">                                              
        <a href="test">test</a>
    </div>
    <p>
        <span class="test two">Nuevo</span>
    </p>                                            

    <div class="bold2">  
        <a href="test">test</a>
    </div>
    <p>
        i want to get this text
    </p>
</div>
```

This is my selenium code:

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("content1/p[2]"));
```

can anyone help me correct my selenium code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option #1** (assuming that these are the **first** `<p>` elements in the DOM):

```
element = driver.findElements(By.tagName("p")).get(1);
```

**Option #2**:

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='content1']/p[2]"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath isn't valid in the first place. Did you mean `.//div[@class='content1']/p[2]`?

Please try

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='content1']/p[2]"));
```

Here is another XPath you can also have a try, which doesn't require indexing.

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='content1']/div[@class='bold2']/following-sibling::p"));
```

Note that if the HTML isn't the real one you are testing, you might face other issues, the above XPaths only provide the logic.

Comment: i think there is an automater at work.. PROBABLY with selenium. look at your rep.  it has happened to myself, you, the other answerer and even the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I've answered a question similar to this that could help you:

[Selecting Nth-of-type in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909458/selecting-nth-of-type-in-selenium/19909750#19909750)

If you are interested in CSS, I'd check this out.  If you are wondering on how to use CSS with selenium, check out this blog post: http://ddavison.github.io/css/2014/02/18/effective-css-selectors.html