# How to select css nth-child(3n+1) selector using class name

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use `nth-child` selector by class name.**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/VrFtJ/)**

**HTML**:

```
<div>
<span class="head">Heading</span>
<div class="span">1</div>
<div class="span">2</div>
<div class="span">3</div>
<div class="span">4</div>
<div class="span">5</div>
<div class="span">6</div>
<div class="span">7</div>
<div class="span">8</div>
<div class="span">9</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.span:nth-child(3n+1){
    color: red;
}
```

why is not selecting first child form the `.span` class.?

I need some explanation.

Comment: Because "nth-child" refers to children relative to the parent, not your selector (and first .span is the 2nd child of div)

Comment: Have a look at `http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/`

Comment: I elaborate on this a little bit here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909458/selecting-nth-of-type-in-selenium/19909750#19909750

Comment: @sircapsalot: The answer you linked is wrong

Comment: @onetrickpony what part in particular?

Comment: The part with nth-of-type: *Find anything with a class of c1 that is a second child*. That's nth-child. nth-of-type also takes the element type into account when counting

Answer (score 3):

When using a formula (an + b). a represents a cycle size, n is a counter (starts at 0), and b is an offset value.

This may be a little tricky **but the indexing of elements here start from 2**

b=2 would means the first element is always choosen.
So,
4n+2 would mean starting with 1st element and adding 4 in cycle=1,5,9.

The value of n starts at 0.

Similarly b=3 would mean starting from the 2nd element
You can not choose 1st element of the ".span" in the series with nth-child=3n+1.

1For your series 1,3,6,9... '1' seems to be out of order.
If you need to choose  first element along with others in your series:

Add

```
.span:nth-child(2){
    color: red;
}
```

Hope it explains the use of nth-child.
For more reference http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/