# Selecting a Button Using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
        <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
            <span class="ui-button-text">

                Export

            </span>
        </button>
        <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
            <span class="ui-button-text">

                Cancel

            </span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

For above html, I want  to select `Export` button. But the following codes didn't work. What's wrong?

```
find_element_by_css_selector('Export').click()
find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(), 'Export')]").click()
find_element_by_link_text('Export').click()
```

Comment: What's your result when you set to a variable e.g `rslt = find_element_by_link_text('Export').click()`

Comment: NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find_element_by_css_selector('Export').click()
```

This will not work because it's looking for an `<Export>` element which obviously does not appear.

```
find_element_by_link_text('Export').click()
```

This will not work because the button is not an `<a>`.  `by_link_text` will only look for `<a>` elements.

```
find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(), 'Export')]").click()
```

Not completely sure why this wouldn't be working, but i'm not an xpath guy.. I preach CSS.

Try this:

```
find_element_by_css_selector('div.ui-dialog-buttonpane > div.ui-dialog-buttonset > button:nth-child(1)").click()
```

Comment: yes your css preaching really worked! could you explain this code?

Comment: i would be happy to know meaning of button:nth-child(1)

Comment: sure!  take a look at my blog post, I explain more about css selectors, and how my thought process was: http://ddavison.github.io/css/2014/02/18/effective-css-selectors.html

Comment: per the nth-child() thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909458/selecting-nth-of-type-in-selenium/19909750#19909750

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped !